# Load a region in higher resolution with JAXA Earth API plugin in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, dem

I am trying to get elevation data for whole countries from AW3D30, but the plugin for QGIS - JAXA Earth API - only seems to allow loading a region equivalent to your screen at a time, and at an insufficient resolution at that. The color scale also seems to be relative to your position, rather than global, which prevents you from loading multiple tiles subsequently to form a complete high res country.
[image]

How to load any whole country at high resolution? This is an example, I also need countries other than Australia.

Answer (score -1):

Did you see the API reference?
https://data.earth.jaxa.jp/api/python/examples2.html
https://data.earth.jaxa.jp/api/python/jaxa.earth.html

Comment: I am illiterate when it comes to code, just a button clicking monkey at this point. Is there a way to load the whole country at a set resolution just from the interface, without using python?

Comment: Maybe it's not possible, because plugin seems not to have set resolution option...

Comment: Got it! Thanks for the advice